# Creating gaps in a dataset

Tags: r

This might be very basic in R, but I am trynig to think of a way how to do this and have no idea how to google it.

I have this:

`Age Count
  1     5 
  2     1 
  3     2 
  4     1 
  5     1`
 
and I want this:

`Age Count
 1-5   10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Int=findInterval(Age,c(1,5),rightmost.closed = T),
         Age=ifelse(Int==1,"1-5",Age)) %>% 
  group_by(Age) %>% 
 summarise(Count=sum(Count))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Age   Count
  <chr> <int>
1 1-5      10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `cut` function.

This will put `age` in intervals specified via the `breaks` argument.

```
d$int <- cut(d$Age, breaks = c(-Inf, 5), labels = "1-5") # create your new interval

#d
#   Age Count int
# 1   1     5 1-5
# 2   2     1 1-5
# 3   3     2 1-5
# 4   4     1 1-5
# 5   5     1 1-5
```

Use `aggregate` to `sum` by the new `int` column

```
aggregate(Count ~ int, data=d, sum)
#    int Count
# 1 1-5    10
```

Data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "Age Count
  1     5 
                2     1 
                3     2 
                4     1 
                5     1", header=T)
```